# Does disabled hyperthreading double the performance on single thread?

Tags: cpu, performance, hyper-threading

I have processor with 4 cores (Intel Core I5-8250U @ 1.6 GHz)* and hyperthreading makes it 8 logical processors.

I use a program that does some heavy calculation* in a single thread. When I look up the program in Task Manager (Win 10 home) I see cpu usage of 20%. However the Resource Monitor shows only 12.5% (also I can confirm there that the program is running just 1 thread).

In Task Manager it looks like one of the 8 logical processors is running at 100% while others are idling. The load is switching between the logical processors every second or so.

My question is: Does hyperthreading only allow 12.5% cpu usage per thread or is there some clever system that allows it to use 25%? I read a few articles that suggested 25% but it wasn't explicitly stated anywhere (and my observation seems to suggest 12%).

*I know I should use a faster computer for this stuff but this is what I have at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By disabling the Hyperthreading you will have only four cores. As a result the maximum CPU time available will be 1/4 *per core* which is 25%. So a task using a full core will change from showing 12.5% to 25%.

This does not mean that you will have more CPU power available though, as a process that only uses one core can still only use one core, regardless of how many cores you have in total.  It just means that what is shown to you *looks* larger because you have a lower total available.

There might be some small improvement in speed due to not sharing the cache between the two Hyperthreaded cores, but it will be the order of a few seconds across a task that takes a few minutes, it will not mean a doubling in speed.

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense. So it's just the matter of me not understanding what the indications of resource monitor actually mean.

Comment: The resource monitor doesn't see that one of the logical processors has eaten all of the resources of the other because it treats both of them as physical.

Comment: @Puzzledstudent yes, as far as the task/resource manager is concerned logical and physical processors are identical. For task scheduling purposes they are the same. Down at the actual core of the CPU is where it makes a difference and for a lightly loaded system it wont matter which "side" of a core it gets loaded on and for heavily loaded systems being able to schedule 2 tasks might mean that the core is able to be fully utilised instead. I did some testing with video transcoding and 4 cores with Hyperthreading is actually faster than plain 4 cores. https://superuser.com/a/279662/19943