# lshw shows wrong CPU count

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, cpu-cores

I have a Samsung NP550P7C laptop with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz

Under Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, lscpu and /proc/cpuinfo detect 4 CPUs
but lshw only shows 2 CPUs

Could there be some sort of misconfiguration or am i getting something wrong?

Here some details, I hope these are the relevant lines:

ubuntu 12.04:

```
lshw:
...
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=laptop cpus=2 family=SAMSUNG SENS sku=SAMSUNG SENS Series ...
...
     *-cpu:0
...
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 id=1 threads=4
...
     *-cpu:1
...
          configuration: id=1
...
```

There is no cpu:2 or cpu:3

Under Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) there is only one block of cpu information:

```
lshw:
....
    *-cpu
...
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
...
```

Comment: That's because you only have a single physical CPU with two cores and four hardware threads (hyperthreading).

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The information you provided is correct.  You have a single CPU with two physical cores and each support Hyperthreading.

Comment: Thanks Bob I wasn't aware of the ambiguous meaning of CPU. Indeed, like lscpu and proc/cpuinfo, dmesg reports 4 CPUs. Hyperthreading was enabled all the way. Meanwhile, I also found this short explanation http://superuser.com/questions/700430/what-does-2-core-4-threads-mean-in-cpu So I understand there is no configuration problem, which was my main concern. @Canadian Luke: Tried to, but not enough reputation to comment or upvote. Or is there another way? BTW as a newbie I can't see yet why it has to be a comment in order to help future visitors. Mind giving me a short explanation or a link whe

Answer (score 2):

That CPU has two Cores and four Threads as per the [Intel ARK website](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/):

```
Processor Number    i5-3210M
# of Cores  2
# of Threads    4
```

If you make sure HT is enabled in your bios this may change to show you four however you may have to check the output from " dmesg | grep CPU " to see the four threads..