# Threads (versus cores) and rated CPU clock speed, what is the effect?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, threads, clockspeed, core

If my CPU is rated at 2GHz, and has 4 cores supporting 8 threads, are all 8 threads running at the rated clock speed? Or are they running at 1GHz each since there are twice as many threads as cores?

Comment: They run at 2 GHz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, cores do not "have" threads. A thread is a property of a process. Processes and threads are things the operating system creates and the CPU really has no direct concept of them. Advertisers who claim their product has "four cores and eight threads" are using misleading terminology.

Your cores have either one or two *logical processors*. As far as the OS is concerned, a logical processor (LP) is something that *can run* a thread. You have one LP per core if you have disabled hyperthreading in the firmware settings, or if your CPU doesn't support HT. Two LPs per core if it supports HT. (Future x86/x64 processors may implement more than two LPs per core.)

The processes in a typical Windows system might have, collectively, anywhere from hundreds to thousands of threads at any given time. You can see the number of threads in each process in Task Manager's "Details" tab (called the "Processes" tab in Windows 7 and earlier) - just enable the "Threads" column.

The vast majority of the threads in most Windows system are "waiting" for something most of the time: They're waiting for I/Os to complete, they're waiting for timers to expire, they're waiting for a page fault to be resolved. Threads that are waiting - Unix and Linux use the term "blocked" - aren't trying to use CPU time and don't use any until whatever they're waiting for happens.

Most threads that aren't waiting are either "running", which means they're actually executing on a logical processor, or "ready", which means they would be running but all the LPs are busy with other threads at the moment. (Aside from Ready, Running, and Wait, there are a few other states that aren't of interest here.)

Everything that follows concerns only "running" threads.

If you don't have HT enabled, or if you have HT enabled but the number of not-waiting threads is no higher than the number of cores, then performance should be identical to HT being disabled. Most modern operating systems, including Windows, try to use only one LP per core until there are more Running threads than LPs. It would (usually) make no sense to put two threads into the LPs of one core while leaving both of the LPs in another core idle. OSs are not always 100% successful at this, but most of the time they do pretty well.

If two LPs in a core are both running threads, then the sum of the "computing" work done by the two threads will *probably* be somewhat greater... generally by 40 to 60%... than if you had just one core that the OS was time-slicing between the two threads. And the total work done will almost certainly be somewhat less than if each thread was running on a core by itself.

Note that a thread that's Running (as far as the OS knows) may nevertheless be stalled in its LP. A common case of this is when the thread has accessed RAM that isn't in the CPU L1 cache yet. It takes time to bring the required data from the outer level cache, or from RAM, into the L1 cache. During this time the thread may be making no progress in its instruction stream, but Windows doesn't know that. The CPU firmware might use that time to do some work in the other LP in the core. Or it might do some out-of-order work for the thread that's awaiting the RAM contents. The OS is blissfully unaware of such things, just reports the thread as "Running", and continues to accumulate its "CPU time used" even though it may be making no forward progress during the "stall".

So... we can run two threads at a time via Hyperthreading, one on each LP in a core. But that does not mean that each core now has two cores' worth of computing resources ("execution units"), nor does it mean that the clock speed is divided between the two LPs.

Hyperthreading takes advantage of the fact that most threads do not fully utilize all of a core's execution units all the time. In fact, that situation is quite rare... And that's why HT can do as well as it does.  HT allows a second thread to coexist in the processor *at the same time* as the first, and ideally this second thread can use execution units that the first does not. This is implemented in the CPU's microcode.

In fact there is really no distinction in the CPU firmware between the "first" and "second" threads; it does not choose to give one more attention than the other.  The firmware just tries to keep as many of the CPU's execution units as busy as possible, getting as much work done as possible. Hyperthreading simply gives it two instruction streams to work on at one time, thereby using more of the CPU's execution units more of the time.

The CPU firmware is not even really aware of what OS's regard as threads, nor "thread context switches", at all. It just knows it has two different instruction streams to work on, each having their own set of values for instruction pointer, stack pointer, and many of the other architectural registers. And sometimes, for reasons unknown to the firmware, the OS comes along and changes all that stuff (a thread context switch).

Another thing HT does not do is implement any part of the OS's notion of thread priority. So if you have two threads in the LPs of a single HT'd core, and the OS thinks those threads have different priorities, the HT firmware in the CPU will not know about that. In particular, it will not assign execution units preferentially to the higher-priority thread. The OS does use thread priorities to decide which threads to choose to run on which CPUs.

For more on how hyperthreading works, see [this article](https://arstechnica.com/features/2002/10/hyperthreading/) at Ars Technica. Unfortunately the illustrations do not appear since they rehosted their site - maybe an email to them would fix that. For more on how Windows "schedules" threads, see the "Scheduling" chapter of *Windows Internals* by Solomon, Russinovich, *et al*.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, your operating system sees your number of threads as the number of cores. When one thread is not at full capacity, it uses the other thread more  and your computer is faster. (I think)

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state. Wondering since you say ***I think*** so I was curious if this is an answer or a guess. Nonetheless, read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.