# Why is my laptop both dual core and quad core at the same time

Tags: cpu, multi-core, core

I bought an [Alienwaremx14](http://www.dell.com/sg/p/alienware-m14x/pd) with the following specifications , it is clearly stated here that my CPU is dual core

[image]

However when i open Window task manager , I was shocked to find out I had four CPU processors running , it now is a quad core CPU

[image]

I am confused over whether my computer is quad core or dual core or both , what is happening ???

Comment: The first screenshot clearly indicate it's a dual core with HT

Comment: @Ramhound: Are you getting that from the model number (which doesn't necessarily equate to the active configuration)?  Or am I missing something in the first screenshot?  Pretty sure the repeated 2.5GHz means nothing, one is part of the model number text and the other is detected clock speed.

Comment: Yes; I looked up the CPU on the Intel website, just like everyone else did

Comment: @Ramhound If you need to consult the Intel website to look up the processor capabilities, then the screenshot does not, in fact, clearly indicate the answer.

Comment: Well, your computer has at least 2 cores, so it's dual-core, and it has exactly 4 cores, so it's quad-core. (I know this isn't the answer, but I just couldn't resist)

Answer (score 46):

What you are seeing is a feature of your CPU called [Hyper-Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which appears as additional logical processors to the OS.

From [Intel's Ark page about that CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA?q=i5-3210m):

> Cores - 2 
>   Threads - 4  
>   Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology - Yes

From there as well:

> Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology (Intel® HT Technology) delivers *two processing threads per physical core*. Highly threaded applications can get more work done in parallel, completing tasks sooner.

A related SU question worth checking out on the subject: [Hyper-Threading and Dual-Core, What's the Difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/133082/hyper-threading-and-dual-core-whats-the-difference?rq=1)

Answer (score 11):

It's because your CPU supports hyperthreading.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-(3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA

Answer (score 8):

[your Chip](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA) has [Hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which allows it to run two threads on each core semi-synchronously. This capability presents itself to the OS as additional cores.

Comment: It must be a CPU with 2 cores, and 2 threads/core.

Comment: thats an oversimplification, but more or less correct.