# Duplication of Architecture State means physically extra?

Tags: windows, hyper-threading

Hyper-Threading Technology makes a
single physical processor appear as two logical
processors; the physical execution resources are shared
and the architecture state is duplicated for the two
logical processors.

So, this means that there are two sets of basic registers such as Next Instruction Pointer, processor registers like AX, BX, CX etc physically embedded in the micro-processor chip,

OR they(arch. state) are made to look two sets by some low level duplication by software/OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Intel implementation, there's another set of registers.

See [What is hyper-threading and how does it work?](https://superuser.com/questions/122536/what-is-hyper-threading-and-how-does-it-work?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, just wanted to be sure that there is a 100% extra/another set of physical registers.